# Applying a transition to a span with in a div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have caption at the bottom of a image that is displayed on `div:hover`. However,

#### The span revealed on div:hover instantly appears despite its transition properties.

After inspecting the element in chrome's dev tools it seems that the transitions are correctly applied to the element but the effect is still instant. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm looking to achieve this effect with just css.

Please checkout an example of the image here:

http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/Am244/3/

html:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="">
    <span>Im a caption</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
     -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.25s ease-out;

}
span {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}
div:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display` isn't a [supported property](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/) for transitions. You can however use `opacity` for this:

```
span {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
   /* display:none;*/
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 1.25s ease-out;
}
div:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    /*display: block;*/
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/Am244/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I just found this out myself in the fiddle. Is there anyway to transition the display effect without js?

Comment: What do you mean? What kind of effect are you looking for? Because `display: none;` has no real effect.